# How to remove item from string c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i need help to make code to delete item. mycode is here

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int money = 0;
    public Text moneytext;
    public Text inventory;

    public void additem(string item)
    {
        moneytext.text = money.ToString();
        inventory.text += "\n" + item;
    }
}
```

i want make deleteitem i try this but error. thankyou for your help

```
public void deleteitem(string item)
{ moneytext.text = money.ToString();
inventory.text -= "\n" + item;}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve with deleteitem?

Comment: Uh I see. Try the `Replace()` method. You cannot use `-` with string.

Comment: i want remove my itemlist when i click delete button

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the items in the string, it is probably better to store them in a list instead and join them together when you need a string representation of them.

Add this to your variables for a list to hold your items:

```
List<string> items = new List<>();
```

You can add and remove items to/from the list like this:

```
items.Add(item);
items.Remove(item);
```

When you need a string representation of your list, you can use this:

```
String.Join("\n", items);
```